# I have tons of UInt8 data that is a picture. How do I create an image from this?

Tags: php, image, png

Sorry for the very open ended question, but I have a dumped file that looks like this:

```
 1 TypelessData image data (174776 items)
  0 int size = 174776
  [0]
   0 UInt8 data = 85
  [1]
   0 UInt8 data = 69
  [2]
   0 UInt8 data = 53
  [3]
   0 UInt8 data = 38
  [4]
   0 UInt8 data = 0
  [5]
   0 UInt8 data = 255
  [6]
   0 UInt8 data = 255
  [7]
   0 UInt8 data = 0
  [8]
   0 UInt8 data = 63
  [9]
   0 UInt8 data = 47
  [10]
   0 UInt8 data = 31
etc..
```

This should be a PNG image. Where do I start looking? Is there any way to create a PNG from this using PHP? (I can write some code that converts the data into a PHP array) but I have no idea what to look for here. Thanks!

Here are more data:

```
Width: 512
Height: 512
Size: 174776
```

Comment: Those data bytes are not the magic signature for a PNG file, so your starting premise is wrong.

Comment: Do you mean it *IS* a PNG image, or you want it to *BECOME* one? At the moment, as @Jongware says, the first few bytes do not correspond to a PNG file. Also, if you multiply the height by width, you get 262,144 pixels whereas you have 174,776 values, so you have 2/3 byte/pixel which implies your data is compressed somehow and is not raw.

Comment: I want it to become one! And thanks for the response Mark, I'm looking more closely into this data format now. Especially glad you pointed out that the first bytes doesn't correspond (now I know what PNG bytes looks like) and also how the width/height doesn't correspond with the amount of data.

Comment: Then you need to know what color or alpha each of these data bytes represent - the source format. There doesn't seem to be enough information to do so.